If the stalks of the base change are domains, then must the stalks of the original scheme be domains?
Suppose $X$ is a reduced scheme of finite type over $k$ and let $\ell$ be an algebraic extension of $k$. Suppose the stalks of the base-change $X_{\ell}$ are domains. Must the stalks of $X$ be domains as well?

The difference between your title question and your body questions is going to make it hard for people to answer this. I might suggest making it a little more clear what the question you're asking here is, along with any strategy restrictions you'd like to impose.

Thanks! I edited the question to leave only the specific question I'm interested in. Hope it's an improvement!
